# In Power BI How do I turn off aggregation for decimal numbers on a stacked bar chart?

Tags: decimal, powerbi, dax, aggregation

I have 2 columns of Decimal numbers where I want to report the actual value of the number, not the SUM, not the COUNT, the actual value.  Wen I drop the Summarization selection list, Count is selected and I am unable to de-select it - clicking on it just leaves the selection checked and closes the list.  Show Value As is set to No Calculation.

I have verified that the data type is Decimal, formatted to 2 decimal places.  Default Summarization level is set to Do Not Summarize.
When I add one or both columns to the Visualization Pane they default to  Count of .

The two columns are the result of Summarization.  Essentially a total expressed as Percent Complete and Percent Reworked.

```
ByPerByState =
SUMMARIZE (
    'periodResults',
    periodResults[period],
    periodResults[workFlow State],
    "Period Complete", SUM ( 'periodResults'[Completed] ),
    "Period Reworked", SUM ( 'periodResults'[Reworked] ),
    "Total", SUM ( 'periodResults'[Completed] ) + SUM ( 'periodResults'[Reworked] ),
    "PercentComplete", DIVIDE (
        SUM ( 'periodResults'[Completed] ),
        ( SUM ( 'periodResults'[Completed] ) + SUM ( 'periodResults'[Reworked] ) ),
        0
    ),
    "Percent Reworked", DIVIDE (
        SUM ( 'periodResults'[Reworked] ),
        ( SUM ( 'periodResults'[Completed] ) + SUM ( 'periodResults'[Reworked] ) ),
        0
    )
)
```

Comment: That's not how the charts are intended to work. I'd recommend writing measures for your chart rather than calculating a summary table and trying to reference that.

Comment: Is there a different chart type that would be more appropriate in PBI ?  This is simplicity itself in Excel which makes me wonder what I'm missing ... My understanding - which may be flawed - was that measures are not generally a row by row application.  My rows are unique as they represent  the throughput in workflow states in specific reporting periods.

Comment: The visuals in Power BI work just like a pivot chart. It's just a different way of doing things. Measures certainly can be implemented row-by-row using iterator functions like `SUMX` instead of `SUM`.

Comment: Could you please post an image of the visualization you are trying to build?

Comment: I’ll try to do that.  I was able to solve my issue and get the stacked bar chart to work.  I ended up doing 2 calculated columns in DAX rather than a ‘virtual’ table using DAX Summarize.  The calculated values allow me to disable the aggregation.